# 6" recessed can light to track light

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light

I have a single 6" can light which isn't good enough for our needs in our entrance hallway. I want to know if there is a way to convert it to a track light and that way attach multiple lights to the track?

I tried googling, and I found things like 
[image]

but it seems that suitable for changing a recessed can to a pendent... we want a track.

I saw this, 
[image]

(or these http://www.bellacor.com/track-lighting.htm) but I don't like the design(s).

I'm after something a bit more simple/sleek like

http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/1000/89/898b12d5-9ef9-47c5-8d2a-dd5974d1a8d8_1000.jpg

Can I get a 6" recessed can adapter that is universal for track lights? Do they exist?

P.S Even better would be 6" recessed can to a track light extension (drop the height of the track 6" from the ceiling).

Comment: Can you access the can light from above? Or is the hole large enough to remove the can?

Comment: I can't access the can light from above. i believe the can was a new construction, so I can't pull it out of its hole

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I've not done this, nor do I know NEC. I'm basing this off my experiences

I think the pendant conversion kit might suffice. Your track lighting (the second one, not the first) will be screwed into the ceiling directly. The pendant adapter uses the hot and the neutral of the light socket and then probably grounds off the fixture itself (hence the metal clip). Your track lighting would simply pigtail to the wiring adapter.

The catch here is that the cover for the power adapter is probably not large enough to cover the hole for the can light. And the track might not sit flush over the metal adapter in the picture (if it's flat it might, but if it's not flush with the ceiling, or a convex cover, it probably won't). So it might not look very neat. I'm not sure if they would make a cover large enough, but you might be able to fabricate one from a flat plate if needed (i.e. cut the plate to size, cut a hole in the middle and then screw to the fixture)

Comment: yeah, you've got the main problem, which is the box probably isn't big enough to cover the can hole. I want it to look neat and be to code (for when the house catches on fire :\ )

Answer (score 1):

Why not cut out a piece dry wall to cover and patch the hole it is easy enough and you can place your mount - the end result will be that it looks right, not like someone had a can in the ceiling and then placed a track light over the hole. 
They might sell you scraps of dry wall at your hardware store - ask you might be surprised that they have them - sometimes some break apart in handling. (Although a big board is about $15.00 ).

In the ceiling you can be a bit sneaky, run a small screw through the center of your circular piece of dry wall - use a stir stick with a hole in the center for your screw to go into. Place the stir stick above in the ceiling and then run the the screw from the drywall piece into it - it will hold it in place for you and your repair.

Although for me in this case I like to run a board from joist to joist so it is more secure and you can drill or cut the opening you want for the track light. 
This way you can run your 3 wires directly to the track light.. and all will be well.

**EDIT 2/28/2017**
 As for texture or popcorn or not - paint does change color over time. The paint will probably be a satin or matte finish, matching the color can be done by taking a small sample from around the can hole (big enough for a machine to read the color.). Practice first then do, especially if it is a textured ceiling. I find the can is best for knockdown textures, the popcorn I would do manually for that small of an area - dabbing the brush in the paint and then into my popcorn and then dabbing on the ceiling the tip of the brush - straight against the ceiling (holding brush with handle inline floor to ceiling) and dab around - no specific pattern.

BTW: They do make hanging track lights:
Amazon dot com  Search in Tools & Home Improvement : Hanging track light.
see additional edit about painting. But I think the search at A will provide you a simpler fix - if you can find a style you like.

Comment: Home Depot at least (not seen this at any other) offers 2' x 2' sections for small patches. That having been said, if the ceiling is popcorn or textured, replacing drywall is a nightmare. You'll never match the original texture (it slightly changes color over time), so the patch will stand out. That's why I always paint ceilings instead of texture.

Comment: I'm putting drywall over the can hole? That it doesn't sound like it's to code, right? I've got plain drywall at the end of a can?

Comment: @Prof remove the can and place a power box if one is not already there - you are going to be placing a track light - so it has to get its power somehow.  or just remove the can and install the box - it is really easy to do. see additional edit.